# function not fetching data from firebase also showing no error

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function to fetch data from firebase firestore everything working fine except its not fetching data and it also shows no error I don't know why please help me out here

my code functions like I would pick a document name using a list picker and tap the get button(inside map page) and it should fetch the data from the database and give results for the specific page

inside the function(fetchmap)the loading bar is also not working I don't know why?

here is my code:

Mappage.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:helping_hand/UI/Other/Emergency.dart';
import 'package:list_picker/list_picker.dart';

import '../../StateManagement/MapController.dart';
import '../../drawers/bottomnavbar.dart';
import '../Bottom Navigation/My status.dart';

class Mappage extends StatelessWidget {
    Mappage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   final TextEditingController selectPage = TextEditingController();
   final List<String> pageList = ['helps','sitrep','location','emergencies', 'users',];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MapController mapcontroller = Get.find();
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                            child: GetBuilder<MapController>(builder: (_)=>GoogleMap(initialCameraPosition:MapController.initial,
                              mapType: MapType.normal,markers:mapcontroller.markers,
                                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
                                mapcontroller.completercontrol.complete(controller);
                                mapcontroller.googleMapController = controller;
                              },),)
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            top: 50,
                            height: 60,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                                    child: ListPickerField(label:'select', items:pageList,controller:selectPage,)),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                    style:const ButtonStyle(backgroundColor:MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.redAccent)) ,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if(selectPage.text.isNotEmpty){
                                        mapcontroller.fetchMap(selectPage.text);
                                      }else{
                                        Get.snackbar('error','select a page from dropdown menu');
                                      }
                                    },
                                    child:const Text('Get',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
                                FloatingActionButton(
                                  heroTag: 'btn1',
                                  onPressed:(){
                                    Get.to(()=>Emergency());
                                  },
                                  child: const Icon(Icons.emergency_outlined),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 50,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [
                                ElevatedButton(
                                    style:const ButtonStyle(backgroundColor:MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.redAccent)) ,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Get.offAll(()=>Nav());
                                    },
                                    child:const Text('Go to Dashboard',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
                                FloatingActionButton(
                                  heroTag: 'btn2',
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      mapcontroller.getlatlong();
                                    },
                                    child:const Icon(Icons.location_on,color: Colors.white,)),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GetBuilder<MapController>(builder: (_){
              if (mapcontroller.isloading == true) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,color: Colors.white,),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return const SizedBox.shrink();
              }
            }),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

and my mapcontroller (function is fetchmap at the bottom)(using getx):

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:helping_hand/UI/Map/Mappage.dart';

class MapController extends GetxController{
  String locationmessage = 'currentlocation of user';
  late String lat ;
  late String long ;

  Set<Marker>markers={};

  @override
  void onInit() {
    lat = '10.228370';
    long ='76.198799';
    super.onInit();
  }

  late GoogleMapController googleMapController;

  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Completer<GoogleMapController> get completercontrol => _controller;

  static  CameraPosition initial =  const CameraPosition(target:LatLng(10.228370,76.198799),zoom: 15);

  //lower part

  Future<Position> getCurrentLocation() async {
    bool serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('the location is not enabled');
    }
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error(
            'location permissions are permanantly denied, cannot grant acess');
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
          'location permissions are permanantly denied, cannot grant acess');
    }
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  void liveLocation() {
    loadingbar();
    LocationSettings settings = const LocationSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      distanceFilter: 100,
    );
    Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: settings)
        .listen((Position position) {
      lat = position.latitude.toString();
      long = position.longitude.toString();
      googleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target:LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude),zoom: 15)));
      markers.clear();
      markers.add(Marker(markerId:const MarkerId('current user location'),position: LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude)));
      update();
    });
    loadingbaroff();
  }

  void getlatlong(){
    loadingbar();
    getCurrentLocation().then((value){
      lat = '${value.latitude}';
      long = '${value.longitude}';
      googleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target:LatLng(value.latitude,value.longitude),zoom: 15)));
      markers.clear();
      markers.add(Marker(markerId:const MarkerId('current user location'),position: LatLng(value.latitude,value.longitude)));
      update();
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(lat);
      }
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(long);
      }
      liveLocation();
    });
    loadingbaroff();
  }

  void liveLocationToUpload(){
    LocationSettings settings = const LocationSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      distanceFilter: 100,
    );
    Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: settings)
        .listen((Position position) {
      lat = position.latitude.toString();
      long = position.longitude.toString();
      update();
    });
  }

  //MAP PAGE CONTROLLER CONTROLLS ::::::::::::::

  List<DocsForMap> docsformap=[];
  Future<void> fetchMap(String page)async {
    print('this is starting of fetch map');
    loadingbar();
    update();
    print('after loading bar $isloading');
    docsformap.clear();
    print('cleared the values of list');
    final CollectionReference maps = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('map').doc('maps').collection(page);
    try{
      print('inside try catch');
      var data = maps.get();
      print('this is dataaa ::::: $data');
      maps.get().then((snapshot) => (){
        print('inside values::::: $snapshot');
        for (var document in snapshot.docs) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('I AM ACESSING DATA HEREEEEEEEE  :::;;;;;;;;;;');
          }
          if (kDebugMode) {print(document.data());}
        }
      });
    }catch(e){
      Get.snackbar('error','error while fetching $page');
      print('error happenddddd :::::::: $e');
      loadingbaroff();
    }
    loadingbaroff();
  }





  bool isloading = false;

  void loadingbar() {
    isloading = true;
    update();
  }
  void loadingbaroff() {
    isloading = false;
    update();
  }

}
```

my console :

```
min=41.46
I/flutter (14542): this is starting of fetch map
I/flutter (14542): after loading bar true
I/flutter (14542): cleared the values of list
I/flutter (14542): inside try catch
I/flutter (14542): this is dataaa ::::: Instance of 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'
W/DynamiteModule(14542): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(14542): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(14542): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/System.out(14542): [socket]:check permission begin!
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
I/System.out(14542): [socket]:check permission begin!
I/System.out(14542): [socket]:check permission begin!
I/System.out(14542): [socket]:check permission begin!
D/ViewRootImpl(14542): setSurfaceViewCreated, created:false
D/Surface (14542): Surface::disconnect(this=0x7500239000,api=-1)
D/Surface (14542): Surface::disconnect(this=0x755e735000,api=1)
I/BufferQueueProducer(14542): [SurfaceTexture-0-14542-4](this:0x74a100b000,id:7,api:1,p:14542,c:14542) disconnect(P): api 1
I/BufferQueueProducer(14542): [ImageReader-1080x2340f1m3-14542-0](this:0x74cfcc8800,id:0,api:1,p:14542,c:14542) queueBuffer: fps=0.05 dur=600096.19 max=599491.31 min=10.40
I/BufferQueueProducer(14542): [ImageReader-1080x2340f1m3-14542-2](this:0x74cf08b800,id:3,api:1,p:14542,c:14542) queueBuffer: fps=0.05 dur=600100.68 max=599496.03 min=9.76
I/GED     (14542): ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 29, oppidx_max 29, oppidx_min 0
W/le.helping_han(14542): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
D/Surface (14542): Surface::disconnect(this=0x754e09a000,api=1)
E/libprocessgroup(14542): set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following code for method `fetchMap`

```
Future<void> fetchMap(String page) async {
    print('this is starting of fetch map');
    loadingbar();
    update();
    print('after loading bar $isloading');
    docsformap.clear();
    print('cleared the values of list');
    final CollectionReference maps = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('map').doc('maps').collection(page);
    try{
      print('inside try catch');
      var data = await maps.get();
      print('this is dataa ::::: $data');
      for (var document in data.docs) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('I AM ACESSING DATA HEREEEEEEEE  :::;;;;;;;;;;');
        }
        if (kDebugMode) {print(document.data());}
      }
    } catch(e) {
      Get.snackbar('error','error while fetching $page');
      print('error happenddddd :::::::: $e');
    }
    loadingbaroff();
  }
```

Comment: what change did you make? the loading bar is still not working

Comment: Can you send log after this changes

Comment: I changed the code a little bit and it worked finally thankyou so much only the loading bar has a problem now do you have any idea why the loading bar is not showing ?

Comment: In your code, you used `then` which makes the execution async from the main thread. If you are using you code base, then you should call `loadingbaroff` inside `then` callback and also add `catchError` to reset on failure to call `loadingbaroff`. and have to remove `loadingbaroff` outside `then`.

Comment: There might be problem with refresh on `isloading` value